# A novel where almost all of Earth population is killed by some natural event

Tags: story-identification, space

I read this novel less than 10 years ago. And maybe, for once, it was shortly after publication.

Also for once, the destruction of almost all of Earth population is not through a nuclear war, or a cataclysmic event directly caused by mankind, but because of a natural event. I am not quite sure, but IIRC, it was by collision with some huge asteroid. In any case, there was some advance warning, a few months or a few years before it happened.

With so short a time to prepare, it was clear that 99,999... percent of humans were doomed to die. Only a few "Noah's ark" (my choice of words, I don't remember seeing it in the book) could be prepared for a few hundreds, or a few thousands, to save the genome and the scientific knowledge. Some are in space (on the Moon ? on Mars ? on asteroids ? or just in spaceships ? or a combination of all or part of these options ?) but also in deep caves and under the ocean.

Pretty depressing, all in all...

Comment: Isn't this the plot of every post-apocalyptic comet story? See *Lucifer's Hammer* for an example (though that one also had nuclear war).

Comment: @Laurel Well, some general plot maybe. But there are significant details. For instantce, I checked *Lucifer's Hammer* on Wiki. I found the sentence "The scientific community assures the public that a collision with Earth is extremely unlikely". In my story the scientific community took the risk very seriously but the lack of time (just a few years IIRC) did not leave them much choice but a few "Noah's Arks". So clearly my story is **not**  *Lucifer's Hammer*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of Neal Stephenson's [Seveneves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves) from 2015.  It features a disaster (the mysterious conversion of the Moon into a bunch of interacting objects that gradually grind themselves into a dust that will wreck the Earthly environment, a short time frame (about two years) in which any action can be taken, and attempts to preserve a very limited number of humans - some in space, some underground and some under the ocean.

From the wiki-link

> Five thousand years later, there are three billion people living in a
> giant ring of different "habitats" circling the Earth. The population
> is divided into seven races, each of which descends from and is named
> after one of the seven Eves and carries distinct racial
> characteristics that harken back to the personalities and
> characteristics of the original Eves.

---

> "Doc" Hu Noah forms a "Seven" with one member from each race to
> investigate mysterious people who have been sighted on Earth. They
> discover that some humans ("Diggers") have survived the Hard Rain on
> the planet by living in deep mines, and others survived in ocean
> trenches using submarines ("Pingers"); the latter group descends from
> a separate, secret underwater ark that had been created concurrently
> with the Cloud Ark.

Comment: Yes, that's the one !

Answer (score 1):

This could be *[When World's Collide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Worlds_Collide)*, a classic 1933 science fiction novel  by Edwin Balmer and Philip Wylie.

> Sven Bronson, a Swedish astronomer working at an observatory in South Africa, discovers a pair of rogue planets, Bronson Alpha and Bronson Beta, which will soon enter the Solar System. In eight months, they will pass close enough for gravitational forces to cause catastrophic damage to the Earth. Sixteen months later, after swinging around the Sun, Bronson Alpha (a gas giant) will return to pulverize the Earth and depart. Bronson Beta (discovered to be Earth-like and potentially habitable) may remain and assume a stable orbit.
>
> Scientists led by Cole Hendron work desperately to build an atomic rocket to transport enough people, animals and equipment to Bronson Beta to save humanity from extinction. Various countries do the same. The United States evacuates coastal regions in preparation for the first encounter. As the planets approach, observers see through their telescopes cities on Bronson Beta. Tidal waves sweep inland at a height of 750 feet (230 m), volcanic eruptions and earthquakes add to the deadly toll, and the weather runs wild for more than two days. Bronson Alpha grazes and destroys the Moon.

That said, I don't remember any underground sheltering, and the ending is cautiously optimistic, with the survivors landing on Bronson Beta, leading to the sequel, *[After Worlds Collide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Worlds_Collide)*.

Comment: Oh... and I see there's already an accepted answer, but keeping this one up for future querents.